# Rails, day of year to date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I have day of the year. For example 15th day of 2014, or 210th day of 2014. I need to get the Date on the particular day. Is there any library function in Rails/Ruby that I can use, or any other elegant way?

Something like:

15th day of 2014 = 15-Jan-2014

210th day of 2014 = 29-Jul-2014

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Date.ordinal](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-ordinal) for that:

```
require 'date'

Date.ordinal(2014, 210)
# => #<Date: 2014-07-29 ((2456868j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Comment: thank you wonder, I guess I skipped the ordinal function in docs. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Date.new(2014, 1, 1) + 210
=> Wed, 30 Jul 2014
```

Edit - you'd need to subtract 1 day. I prefer @wonderb0lt's suggestion.